# Why i cant get the object value instead of names: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

```js
const Data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "jack"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "george"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "morries"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "kok"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "abdo"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "ezz"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "mostafa"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "tox"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "hamo"
    }]

var new_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
    var data_id = Data[i].id;
    var data_name = Data[i];
    var ref_index = add(new_array, data_id);
    new_array[ref_index].names.push({ data: data_name });

}

console.log(new_array);

function add(data_array, id_value) {
    var index = data_array.findIndex(x => x.id === id_value);
    if (index === -1) {
        data_array.push({ id: id_value, names: [] });
        index = data_array.findIndex(x => x.id === id_value);
    }
    return index;
}
```

why my response like this I need to see the value of my objects and I don't know what am missing!

```js
[
    { id: 1, names: [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]] },
    { id: 2, names: [[Object], [Object]] },
    { id: 3, names: [[Object], [Object]] },
    { id: 4, names: [[Object]] }
]
```

I need to see the object itself so I try the code but it's response like the above of the code?

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:
1- The Spreed Operator.

```
var data_name = {...Data[i]};
```

2- Stringify The Object.

```
var data_name = JSON.stringify(Data[i]);
```

3- The "assign" Method.

```
var data_name = Object.assign({}, Data[i]);
```

Comment: but i wanna the full object not just name

Comment: i mean data_name is just a variable should hold the whole object

Comment: ok, I've edited the comment, try each one of these methods mentioned above.

Comment: still the same resoponse